# PHP redirect with sessions, login and panel php

Tags: php, html

Im doing a website and I'm working right now with the login and panel. When I'm at the panel and I wan't for example to go to another page, it doesn't allow me to redirect, it just refresh itselfs.

```
        <?php 

          session_start();

          require 'database.php';

          if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            $message = 'La sesión esta iniciada';
        } else {
           header('Location: index.php');
        } //Panel code


        Also in login I have this line
        session_start();

  require 'database.php';
                    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        header('Location: panel.php');
    }
```

I hope someone can help me.
Sorry for bad English.
Rewards.
Luis

Comment: how have you named your files. you might have named your files in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
session_start();
require 'database.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: panel.php');
}else{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

session_start();
require 'database.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
     $message = 'La sesión esta iniciada';

}
else{
      header('Location: panel.php');
}

?>
```

In login

```
<?php

session_start();
require 'database.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: panel.php');
}
```

Comment: Now when I try to access the panel while I'm not logged it constantly refresh like a while action, and also the problem continue